# Scrape data of a div after one or two html tags using xpath

Tags: xpath

Here is the code:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="datebar">
      <span style="float:right">some text1</span>
      <b>some text2</b>
Thursday, September 8, 2011 - 1:17 pm EDT
   </div>
</div>
```

I just want to extract date and time `Thursday, September 8, 2011 - 1:17 pm EDT`.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Here at SO you are expected to *accept* the best answer if it solves your problem. To do so, click on the check-mark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div[@id = 'content']/div[@class = 'datebar']/text()
```

or

```
div[@id = 'content']/div[@class = 'datebar']/b/following-sibling::text()
```

Though it should be normalized after.

Comment: `  <div id="content"> 
      <div class="datebar"> 
         <span style="float:right">some text1</span> 
         <b>some text2</b>
       </div>
     <p>paragraph 1</p> 
     <p>paragraph 2</p> 
    </div>

Sir now i want to get data that in <p> tags or you can say that is coming after "databar"'s div